# How to call stored procedure that has spatial parameter in EF core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am using EF Core 2.2.0 and I was trying to call a stored procedure that has a parameter of type `Geometry`. When I call the stored procedure, I get this error:

> Specified type is not registered on the target server.  NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon, NetTopologySuite, Version=1.15.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f580a05016ebada1.

I call the stored procedure like this:

```
// Create IGeometry with NetTopologySuite.Features.Feature
IGeometry zone= feature.Geometry;

var zoneParameter = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@zone",
    Value = zone,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt,
    UdtTypeName = "Geometry"
};

return _context.Query<ReportDTO>()
    .FromSql("mySP {0}", zoneParameter)
    .ToList();
```

My stored procedure is just this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE mySP  
    @zone GEOMETRY
AS
BEGIN
    -- do something
END
```

The SQL Server version is: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Is this not supported on EF Core or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the geometry

```
var geometryWriter = new SqlServerBytesWriter {IsGeography = false};
var geometryBytes = geometryWriter.Write(zone);

var zoneParameter = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@zone",
    Value = geometryBytes,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt,
    UdtTypeName = "Geometry"
};

return _context.Query<ReportDTO>()
    .FromSql("mySP {0}", zoneParameter)
    .ToList();
```